# I can't find the signed request sent from facebook using their registration api in google app engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, request, signed

I am really confused, because the documentation states that when a user registers from my website, using a facebook registration form, I am supposed to receive a signed request. I do not know where to look for it. Any replies would be appreciated. I am using Python in Google App Engine and I am just trying to set up a user authentication with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AppEngine+python and Facebook Authentication.
I think my code will help you.

https://github.com/hanasoo/vis-asq/tree/master/apps/auth

Comment: Thank you for the post, but after seeing your code I still don't understand where facebook seends the signed request. Where can I get the information that the user just submitted?